# Проверить содержимое ячеек таблицы, содержащих checkbox, не указанный как тип

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, javascript-events

Есть таблица, в ней есть столбец, в которой выводятся значения true false, эти ячейки как checkbox без возможности изменить их:

```
<table class="table" id="friendTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Voter)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Voter)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }    
</tbody>
```

Проблема в определении содержимого этих ячеек. Я пытался следующими способами:

- `if (rows[i].cells[0] == true)`
- `if (rows[i].cells[0].checked)`
- `if (rows[i].cells[0].text()==true)`

Но во всех этих способах он возвращает не значение true/false, а undefind или что ещё другое.

Как проверить можно?
Может можно поменять тип содержимого ячейки так чтобы это был checkbox, но без возможности изменения?

Мне это нужно чтобы посчитать количество записей со статусом "true":

```
$('friendTable').ready(function countVoters() {

    var table = document.getElementById('friendTable');
    var rows = table.rows;
    var total = 0;
    
    for (var i = 1, iLen = rows.length - 1; i < iLen; i++) {
        if (rows[i].cells[0] == true) {
            total += 1;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('totalVoter').innerHTML = total.toFixed(0);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rows[i].cells[0] - у вас ячейка (блок), а не конкретный input (checkbox), данный блок может содержать много чего, в том числе и дерево элементов, поэтому нужно достучаться до конечного текстбокса, а это можно сделать поиском getElementsByTagName внутри ячейки.

```
var checked_ = table.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;
if (checked_ == true) {
            total += 1;
}
```

Comment: Не работает: 'jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined' , 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.countVoters'

Comment: У меня в таблице данные ячейки не заданы как 'input', мне не нужно чтобы их можно было менять

Comment: На чистом html+js с стандартным input type=checkbox - работает. В браузере в консоли введите "table.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]" и посмотрите какие свойства у него есть.

Comment: Прошу прощения, мой косяк, работает. Спасибо!